# parallel parMap and strategies

Tags: haskell

It's a doubt about parallel strategies and `parMap` (Control.Parallel.Strategies)

It's about `parMap rseq` equivalence with `parMap rpar`.

Since `parMap` uses `parList` it evaluates in parallel so using either `rseq` or `rpar` will evaluate in parallel to WHNF. Isn't it ?

Update:

Since

```
parMap strat f = (`using` parList strat) . map f

parList = parTraversable

parTraversable strat = evalTraversable (rpar `dot` strat)

evalTraversable = traverse

strat2 `dot` strat1 = strat2 . runEval . strat1
```

---

`parMap rseq` uses the strategy

```
rpar `dot` rseq
```

which gives:

```
rpar . runEval . rseq
```

which gives:

```
(\x -> x `par` return x) . runEval . (\x -> x `pseq` return x)
```

It is hard to think about the result.

---

Update:

I see, the lazy evaluation takes the first function of the composition first, and

```
(\x -> x `par` return x)
```

grants that every element in the traversable container will be sparked for a parallel computation when possible.

So we could add that *(rpar `dot` rseq)* is equivalent to *(rseq `dot` rpar)*, isn't it?

And that `parMap rpar` is redundant in that it generates two sparks for every traversable element. !!

Answer (score 5):

A quick smoke test reveals that yes `parMap rseq` and `parMap rpar` both get evaluated in parallel.

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

main = print resultPlain where
  resultPlain = [fib 34, fib 34, fib 34, fib 34]
  resultPar   = parMap rpar id [fib 34, fib 34, fib 34, fib 34]
  resultSeq   = parMap rseq id [fib 34, fib 34, fib 34, fib 34]
```

and then, using each kind of `result_____` I timed the compiled binaries

```
ghc -threaded --make rpar
time ./rpar +RTS -N4
```

and saw that `resultPlain` was much longer than `resultPar` or `resultSeq` (about 2x longer) and `resultPar` and `resultSeq` were comparatively identically timed.

More details into GHC's actual interpretation of the `Eval` monad are lacking, but given that `parMap strat f = withStrategy (parList strat) . map f` along with the results of this experiment I feel confident saying each element in the list is sparked for evaluation to WHNF.